# File path not getting set using 'save_screenshot' for python selenium in ubuntu

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver

I am using python selenium to get a screenshot of test, but in ubuntu the saved screenshot is taking the path name as file name and getting saved on the desktop. I have used the same code on windows and the file was being saved in the correct destination:

```
def shot():
    ts = time.time()
    path = "\home\sudhanshu\Desktop\shots\sb"
    extension = ".png"
    screensave = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%d%m%Y%H%M%S')
    print (path+screensave+extension)  
    wd.save_screenshot(path+screensave+extension)
```

Here, if you see the path, I want to save the file with timestamp as file name in a folder named shots present on desktop, but it takes the complete path as file name and gets saved on the desktop. The same thing worked perfectly on windows. I have tried adding the path differently like setting `~\sudhanshu\Desktop\shots06062017170730.png` as path but nothing works. Can anyone please suggest something.

Comment: It seems like a separator problem. On windows, \ works but on Linux you should use /

Comment: Initially i tried using /, but it does not work at all...

Comment: This line: `path = "\home\sudhanshu\Desktop\shots\ts"` doesn't do what you expect because `\t` is interpreted as a tab character. Either use `os.path.join` or, if you must use literal backslashes, put them in raw strings: `path = r"\home\sudhanshu\Desktop\shots\ts"`

Comment: Tried doing the same, did not work... any more guesses !!!!

Comment: try `os.path.join(path,screensave+extention)`

Comment: Used the code but did not work... after using os.path.join, the screenshots are not coming even on the desktop... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) and `os.filesep` to manipulate filepaths.

```
import os
import time
def shot():
    ts = time.time()
    path = os.path.join("home","sudhanshu","Desktop","shots","sb")
    extention = ".png"
    screensave = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%d%m%Y%H%M%S')
    print(os.path.join(path, screensave+extention))
    wd.save_screenshot(os.path.join(path, screensave+extention))
```

Comment: `def shot():`
     `ts = time.time()`
     `path = r"\home\sudhanshu\Desktop\shots\ts"`
     `extention = ".png'"`
     `screensave = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%d%m%Y%H%M%S')`
     `new = os.path.join(path, screensave, extention)`
     `wd.save_screenshot(new)`

Answer (score 0):

Started working again by using / and using os.path.join together. Thanks everyone.